# Как скоординировать url.py в Django + REST и роутинг в Angular JS?

Tags: django, angularjs

Как скоординировать `url.py` в `Django + Django REST` и роутинг в `Angular JS`?
Корень сайта `/` не видит, ошибка, что страница не найдена.
Задача: через Django использовать api для заполнения шаблонов данными, через Angular организовать переход между страницами с передачей параметров.

```
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^db_api/
    ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^static\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Роутинг в ангуляре:

```
angular('myApp', ['ngRouter']);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$routerProvider', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider, DJANGO_SETTINGS) {
       $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             controller: 'someController1',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myproject/templates/template1.html'
        }
        .when('/page1/:id', {
             controller: 'someController2',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myproject/templates/template2.html'
        }
};
```

в главном urls.py для myproject:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^db_api/', include("db_manager.urls")),
   ) + static.static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static.static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

в db_manager urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
   url(r'^info', InfoDbAPI.as_view())
```

**Обновление:**

Добавил:

В `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
```

В `views.py`:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

В `index.html` подключается скрипт с роутингом ангуляра и скрипт с контроллерами. При переходе в корень сайта открывается `index.html`, но роутинг не срабатывает. При переходе на `/page1/1` выдается ошибка, что такой путь не зарегистрирован в `urls.py`. Т.е. роутинг ангуляра не срабатывает.

И еще непонятно, если у меня есть базовый шаблон, в котором подключаются базовые скрипты, т.е. общие для всех, есть некий index.html, расширение базового шаблона, в котором подключается скрипт с роутингом ангуляра и его контроллерами для каждой страницы, и есть два шаблона, которые должны открываться на основе правил роутинга ангуляра. 
Какая структура должна быть у этих шаблонов, если изначально они являлись расширениями index.html, т.е. использовали его скрипты, скрипты базового шаблона.

Т.е. base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
подключение общих скриптов, таблиц стилей
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
подключение скриптов, в частности, с контроллерами ангуляра, таблиц стилей, скрипт с роутингом ангуляра
```

template1.html:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
<div ng-app="myApp">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то стоит в `urls.py` добавить паттерн для корневой страницы (/), сделать какой-то `TemplateView`, который будет открывать некий `index.html`, в котором уже подключается ваш `Angular` и дальше все делает уже сам

В `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
```

В `views.py`:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

Comment: сделал так, теперь корень - открывается этот самый index, но роутинг ангуляра не срабатывает. при попытка перехода на `/page1/1`  выдается ошибка, что в `urls.py` такого пути нет. Т.е., если я правильно понимаю, ангуляр не обрабатывает путь